# Why is the actual logic running when mocking a public method in a package-private abstract superclass?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm writing unit tests for a class with a dependency that extends a package-private abstract superclass. The set up is similar to the following:

```
package pkg1;

public class ConcreteClass<T extends Something> extends AbstractClass<T> {

    ...

}
```

```
package pkg1;

abstract class AbstractClass<T extends Something> {

    public AbstractClass() {
        ...
    }

    protected abstract Object unusedAbstractMethod() {
        ...
    }

    public T foo() {
        // this method kicks off another sequence of calls into other classes before returning 
    }

}
```

```
package pkg2;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
    @Mock
    private ConcreteClass<SomeClass> concreteClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(concreteClass.foo()).thenReturn(someClass);

        ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest(concreteClass);

        ...
    }
```

When the line `when(concreteClass.foo()).thenReturn(someClass);` is executed, the test is failing with a NullPointerException. From the stack trace, I can see that the logic in foo() is being executed and the NPE is being generated several layers deep in the resulting call stack. Why is the method actually being run on my mock, and how can I go about mocking it appropriately?

Comment: What version of Mockito are you using? your scenario is working in 2.8.9 version.

Comment: We're using 1.10.8

Answer (score 0):

I think the mocking syntax you want is actually not:

```
when(concreteClass.foo()).thenReturn(someClass);
```

but instead:

```
when(concreteClass).foo().thenReturn(someClass);
```

The way you've written it, it's as if you're asking "concreteClass.foo()" to return the class whose type is mocked.

So say if concreteClass.foo() were some utility class you created that was implemented as { return SomeType.class }, then when(concreteClass.foo()) would give you a mock SomeType object.

Comment: Apologies if the syntax isn't perfect. I'm free-form typing.. But you get the idea!